# border-radius from image to one single item

Tags: html, css

I have something very simple but I don`t understand
how I can settled it to just one single picture ????

In my document I have more pictures standing
& the result is that all pictures are rounded.

```
<style>
img {
border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>

<img src="../Members/<?php echo  $row['post_user_id']?>.jpg" border="none" width="40" height="30"></img>
```

Comment: Give the specific image an ID, and target that in the CSS rather than all images are you do currently.

Comment: _or_ introduce a css-class "rounded" and add that class to that image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something special to happen to one specific element you have to make that element unique, or a member of a special grouping/category. There are a number of ways this is just one

Add a class to your css and then add that class to your element

```
<style>
.special-image {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
```

Now you add the class to only this image, or maybe a couple of them if you like. The css will only apply to those elements that contain this css class.

```
<img class="special-image" src="../Members/<?php echo  $row['post_user_id']?>.jpg" border="none" width="40" height="30"></img>
```

Comment: I don`t understand how I can settled it to just one single picture ????
@Jan Molendijk asked for single picture. in that case writing inline will be affordable.

Comment: Yes, but using a class would be more flexible. And the OP started with  CSS to effect this change so I continued that concept. ___By the way I did not downvote your answer___ if that is why you are commenting at me